# Registry RMI can't find stub class

Tags: java, rmi

When I run my RMI application it's working but when I try my code on a different PC with different addresses I am getting this error:

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested
>   exception is:
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: zz.INTERFCE   at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)    at
>   CLIENT$2.actionPerformed(CLIENT.java:112)     .
>       . 
>       .

ok this is my code :
side of Server

```
                         try {
                         System.setProperty("java.security.policy","C:\\DERNIER\\src\\security.policy");
      System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());

                    registre = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Integer.parseInt(textport.getText()));
                    IMPLIEMENT obj=new IMPLIEMENT();
                    registre.rebind("Hello1",obj);
                    list1.add("serveur is lisning");
                    cpt++;
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Side of client

```
                try {

                     user=txtUN.getText();
                    client=new CLIENT_IMPLMENT(rsa,user);

                     hello= (INTERFCE) Naming.lookup("rmi://"+textadressz.getText()+":"+Integer.parseInt(txtport.getText())+"/Hello1");         
                     hello.connecté((CLIENT_INTERFCE)client,user,rsa.getN(),rsa.getE());
                     cpt++;

                } catch (RemoteException | MalformedURLException | NotBoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

PS : My application work's fine in localhoste

Comment: share your code plz.

Answer (score 1):

You've mis-stated the problem. The class that isn't being found is `zz.INTERFCE`. This is not a stub. It appears to be a remote interface actually. It needs to be deployed at the client. Otherwise the client can't do anything with it anyway.

Comment: zz is the pakage that include the INTERFACE on the Server Side ,the client was able to reach  the pakage but  he wasn't able to reach to  the stub , this is my gess anyway ??

Comment: I don't know why you're guessing when I've told you the answer. 'Reach the package' is meaningless. If '`zz` is the package that includes the interface on the server side' means that you've duplicated the interface into two packages, that's the problem. It has to be the same interface, same name, same package, same definition. Preferably the same .class file.

Comment: thank you verry match my friend ,finally may aplication is working thank's for help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must have the same name of package on the two sides (client and server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Actually it does, although ambiguously expressed.

Comment: well, maybe. As I see it, it merely states something, and does not try to resolve the OP's problem, so it should be a comment. And the thing that it states doesn't seem (at least not from the OP's question) relevant as there is no indication that the package names are different on the client and server.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Evidently you have failed to grasp that Mimir Kader *is* the OP. The indication you seek is to be found in comments under my answer.